# Sharp corners to tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{coloredtheorem}{Theorem}{colback=red!15{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{coloredtheorem}{Pigs}{pig}
Pigs are pink.
\end{coloredtheorem}

\end{document}
```

But I want sharp corners. When I change defining line to

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{coloredtheorem}{Theorem}{colback=red!15, sharp corners}{th}
```

I get

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/sharp corners' . . .
```

Is this a bug in packaging system? I am using Fedora Linux version 20, TeXLive installed from rpm-packages and system is updated with yum.

Comment: I'm quite sure that your version is too old. The log-file contains the version information and it should be `version 3.12 (2014/07/29)` as Harish Kumar wrote in his answer.

Comment: @thomas-f-sturm, you are right. There is `2013/12/17 version 2.60` at my TeXLive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing the closing brace in `colback=red!15{th}` after 15. For me `sharp corners` works though. I am using `version 3.12 (2014/07/29)`.

As an alternative you can add `arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt` as the options to `tcolorbox` to make sharp corners.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{coloredtheorem}{Theorem}{colback=red!15,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{coloredtheorem}{Pigs}{pig}
Pigs are pink.
\end{coloredtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! FYI, I have sent link to this page to creator of `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 7):

My solution. Using `arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt` For The LaTeX package tcolorbox - version 3.04 (2014/05/18).

Documentation of `Ver­sion  4.11 2017-09-14`

> /tcb/sharp corners=<position>            (default all, initially unset)
>
> The <position> denotes one or more of the four box corners to be set as *sharp* corners. The not assigned corners will retain their mode.

[image]

> The /tcb/rounded corners can be used to revert a /tcb/sharp corners setting.

[image]

> /tcb/sharpish corners     (style, no value)
>
> Shortcut for setting /tcb/arc and /tcb/outer arc to 0pt. With this setting, rounded corners will appear as quasi-sharp, but e. g. the shadow will be somewhat rounder than the shadow of really sharp corners.

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Can I also control individual border thicknesses in a likewise fashion? And how to you cast shadows (and can I control whether it's cast from the left/right/straight on)?